# Wolfram Mathematica import data from multiple files

Tags: string, import, wolfram-mathematica

I have a lot of files. Every of which contains data.
I can happy import one file to Mathematica. But there are more than 500 hundreds of files.
I do it so:

```
 Import["~/math/third_ks/mixed_matrices/1.dat", "Table"];
 aaaa = %
  (*OUTPUT  - some data, I can access them!*)
```

All that I want is just to make circle(I can do it), but I cannot change name of file - 1.dat.  I want to change it.

I tried to make such solution. I generated part of possible names and I have written them to separated file.

```
Import["~/math/third_ks/mixed_matrices/generate_name_of_files.dat", "Table"];
aaaa = %
```

Output:  `{{"~/math/third_ks/mixed_matrices/0.dat"}, \`
            `{"~/math/third_ks/mixed_matrices/1.dat"}, ......`

All that I want to do is `Table[a=Import[aaaa[[i]] ,{i,1,500}]`

But the function `Import` accepts only  `String` " " objects as filename/paths.

Comment: By the way there is a Mathematica-specific StackExchange site at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/. Your questions will be answered faster there, and probably you will get more upvotes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `FileNames` to collect the names of the data files you want to import, with the usual wildcards.

And then just map the `Import` statement over the list of filenames.

`data` will then contain a list comprising the data from each file as a separate element.

```
data = Import[#,"Table"]& /@ FileNames["~/math/third_ks/mixed_matrices/*.dat"];
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to work out what is going on without the file of filenames. However, I think you might be able to solve your problem by using `Flatten` on the list of filenames to make it a vector of `String` objects that can be passed to `Import`. Currently your list is an n*1 matrix, where each row is a `List` containing a `String`, not a vector of `String`s.

Incidentally you could use `Map` (`/@`) instead of `Table` in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response.
 
It happened so that I got two solutions in the same time.
 
I think it would be not fair to forget about second way.

```
    aaaa = "~/math/third_ks/mixed_matrices/" <> ToString[#] <> ".dat" & /@  Range[0, 116];
   (*This thing generates list of lines  
     Output:
       {"~/math/third_ks/mixed_matrices/0.dat", \
        "~/math/third_ks/mixed_matrices/1.dat", \
        "~/math/third_ks/mixed_matrices/2.dat",    .....etc, until 116

    Table[Import[aaaa[[i]], "Table"], {i, 1, 117}];
    (*and it just imports data from file*)

    bbbb = %;  (*here we have all data, voila!*)
```

Incidentally, it's not my solution.
It was supposed by one my friend:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243244/light-keeper

Comment: Glad you solved your problem:) There isn't a need to build a table with an index variable in the above  solution. All you need to do is map `/@` the Import statement over the list aaaa ( you don't actually need to assign the list of strings to aaaa either you can just map over list of names ). That's the neat advantage of functional programming over procedural. No need to keep track of how big things are. You just map the function you want over the list, and it works out how long it is:)